# rails 4 model association left join validate id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, activerecord

I have been battling this for a  bit now, I want to create a LEFT join condition, so I have a Coupon model, users can create coupons but they may or may not be assigned to a job, when they are a assigned they are considered executed. I had this setup as `has_one :job` on the coupon model with a `add_reference :jobs, :coupon, index: true` index, but this seems borked. I think my brain is fried today… If coupon is used I would ideally like to confirm that it is assigned to valid job, which is why I was working with the index.

```
class CreateCoupons < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :coupons do |t|
      t.string :code, limit: 250, null: false
      t.datetime :start_at, null: false
      t.datetime :end_at, null: false
      t.datetime :executed_at
      t.datetime :deleted_at
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_reference :jobs, :coupon, index: true
    add_index :coupons, :deleted_at
    add_index :coupons, :code, unique: true
  end
end

class CreateJobs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :jobs do |t|
      t.string :title, limit: 50, null: false
      t.string :slug, limit: 250, null: false
      t.string :location, limit: 100, null: false
      t.string :short_description, limit: 250, null: false
      t.text   :description, null: false
      t.text   :application_process, null: false
      t.boolean :is_featured, default: false
      t.datetime :start_at
      t.datetime :end_at

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :jobs, :slug
  end
end
```

And model classes...

```
class Coupon < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :job
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :coupon
end
```

Comment: The question is unclear. For example, Is there any reason you mentioned LEFT JOIN in the title? What do want to validate?

Comment: @Meier the posted answer has it clearer, I am trying to validate when a coupon is created, later make sure that it is assigned to a valid job id.  thoughts on my follow up to the answer posted below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me start by saying that there's nothing really wrong with what you've got currently, and it's not actually clear what your problem here is.

I would actually model this the other way around, having `job_id` on the `coupons` table, ie.:

```
add_reference :coupons, :job, index:true
```

And...

```
class Coupon < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :job
end
```

The biggest advantage with that is that you can know whether your coupon is executed or not without looking at any other table, if `job_id` is `NULL` then it's not executed - whereas how you have it now you'd need to actually do a SELECT on the `jobs` table just to find out if there was a record with that `coupon_id`

Your `executed?` method would become something like:

```
def executed?
  job_id.present?
end
```

Comment: you have it I think I am testing this now, however, would you move the has_one to the jobs model or leave it off completely?

Comment: Yeah, probably move it there, even if just to document the intent.

Comment: I think I found another race condition, if executed_at date has been added it should validate the job_id is present

Comment: I think I found it validates_presence_of :job, unless: :executed_at?